# How to produce a plot in R for different levels in a variable

Tags: r, plot

I have data which looks similar to this:

```
ID    Time      hgt
1   7 days      3.0
1   30 days     2.5
2   4 days      2.0
2   10 days     1.0
2   15 days     2.5
```

I would like to produce a plot which would show the hgt variable against time for each of the ID, so that I would obtain a plot for ID 1, 2 etc.

What code would achieve this?

Comment: **Welcome to SO!** You have 3 people who tried to help you with an answer. If one or more of the answers have helped you, then please up-vote them. If you have identified a correct or most preferred answer, then please select that answer as the "right one".

Answer (score 0):

If you like to see it at the same plot, I'd use ggplot facet_grid, as long as you don't have a lot of IDs. Let's say your data is called 'data'.

```
if(!"ggplot2"%in%installed.packages()){install.packages("ggplot2")} #check if ggplot2 is installed, and do it otherwise
library(ggplot2) #load the package

ggplot2(data,aes(x=Time,y=hgt))+geom_point()+facet_grid(~ID) #plot it
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also plot two lines on the same plot with the following

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=Time,y=hgt,group=ID))+geom_line(aes(colour=ID))+geom_point(aes(colour=ID))
```

Convert ID to a factor to get a discrete colour scale:

```
 data$ID <- as.factor(data$ID)
```